# Why does XmlSerializer serialize an object to a file containing zeros instead of XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

I have a strange case - it happens at a few customers that a config file saved during runtime using the XmlSerializer is saved as a sequence of zeros (bytes with value 0). The file length is what the expected file size for the given XML output would be (around 350 bytes).

This is the code used for serializing the file:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(path), Encoding.Default))
{
    s.Serialize(sw, this, new XmlSerializerNamespaces());
}
```

The config file model is simple - a class with automatic properties of type string, bool, DateTime and one property of enum type.

- I am sure `File.Create` with some subsequent failure is not causing this - if I do File.Create on an existing file, it just sets its length to zero.
- I tried adding a `throw new Exception()` statement before the `s.Serialize call` - also not the culprit - file is trimmed to zero length

**What could be causing XmlSerializer to output zeros instead of the actual XML?**

Comment: No exceptions while serializing?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the logs when this had occurred so I do not know if there was an exception. I only have access to the config file which is all zeros and obviously cannot be deserialized.

Comment: Mark might be right about [default encoding](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e461f33-de14-46a0-bdb0-fbaeaf409afb/xmlserializer-creating-blank-files?forum=asmxandxml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar question with a perfect answer matching my symptoms:

From Malcolm:

> We've encountered this problem several times at $WORK, **with the
>   symptom being an empty file of the correct size but filled with zero
>   bytes.**
>
> The solution we found was to set the WriteThrough value on the
>   FileStream:

```
using (Stream file = new FileStream(settingTemp, FileMode.Create,
                                   FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
                                   0x1000, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
{
   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Original answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858975/163393

Comment: Could this have to do with the fact that some disk error occurs and the disk is unable to write the contents from the cache to the disk? Faulty disk, crash, ssd without powerloss protection, etc. WriteThrough will force the writer to write straight to disk and not to use the disks cache for performance.

Comment: if this solves the problem, then most likely the system is losing power without being shut down properly, and the disk cache has not been flushed. I think @Ferdy is right.

Answer (score 0):

Simply; it shouldn't. What you describe is atypical. You could *try* being more explicit about owning the file:

```
using (var file = File.Create(path))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.Default))
{
    s.Serialize(sw, this, new XmlSerializerNamespaces());
}
```

However, I would expect your existing code to work. Is there a fully reproducible example that demonstrates generating all-zero output?

Unrelated, but `Encoding.Default` is **virtually never** the right choice. Don't use that. UTF-8 is probably your best default.

I would be looking at things like anti-virus, a failing drive controller, etc...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Adding using around the FileStream would not change anything since StreamWriter.Dispose calls Close on the underlying stream. I do not have a reproducible example and I do not have a proof it is the XmlSerializer producing the file contents. This occurs randomly and only on a few customers machines in different locations. As you said - it could be something external like an antivirus. I wanted to confirm if there is any code path within XmlSerializer which would produce this. I will try to reproduce with different encodings.

Comment: @Marek the encoding thing is separate, but important - it won't cause the 0 problem, but it *could* hurt you down the line for purely encoding reasons.

Comment: when I tried with Encoding.GetEncoding("x-EBCDIC-KoreanExtended") it produced illegible sequence of bytes (maybe just because I do not have the proper character set installed), but I could not reproduce zeros with any of the encodings returned from Encoding.GetEncodings.

Comment: @Marek heh; encodings are fun. Illegible is subjective when dealing with random encodings.